# port forward in INPUT level

Tags: linux, iptables, linux-networking, ip6tables

I want to change the destination port of the ipv6 packet in the INPUT level.

So I tried to use ip6tables with nat in the INPUT level

but seems this command does not work

```
# ip6tables -t nat -I INPUT ! -i br0 -p TCP --dport 8080 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 80
ip6tables v1.2.7a: Unknown arg `--to-ports'
Try `ip6tables -h' or 'ip6tables --help' for more information.
```

I think beside the error returned by iptable, I think that nat is not working in the INPUT level.

So are there a solution to change the destination port of the ipv6 packet in the INPUT level?

I do not want to change it in the PREROUTING level since I do not want change the ipv6 packet that will be forwarded  (not for loacal process)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I want to change the dest port of the received ipv6 packet with dst port = 8080

Comment: You already said that, but you forgot to explain _why_.

Comment: What is your `ip6tables` version and your Linux Kernel version ?

Answer (score 2):

Try something along the lines of this:

```
ip6tables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8080 -j REDIRECT --to-port 80
```

Your packet would not be hitting the INPUT chain for the nat table. Incoming packets go through iptables like so:

On the wire -> `raw:PREROUTING` -> `mangle:PREROUTING` -> `nat:PREROUTING` - > `routing decision` -> `mangle:INPUT` -> `filter:INPUT` -> **Daemon**